# How to wrap a promise

Tags: angularjs, promise, wrapper

How can i wrap a promise in another promise to track its start and end ?
I tried several solutions, but my console.log are never executed :

```
var realPromise = myService.doItAsync();

var defer = $q.defer();
realPromise.then(function(result) {
    console.log("end at " + new Date().getTime()); // <====== never executed
    defer.resolve(result);
}, function(reason){
    console.log("end at " + new Date().getTime()); // <====== never executed
    defer.reject(reason);
});
return defer.promise;
```

See that jsfiddle for complete example : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asicfr/dnakghcb/)

Comment: Can you reduce your jsfiddle to only the relevant and straightforward code (i.e. without any indirection or test platfrom)?

Comment: sounds like `realPromise` is never resolved or rejected.

Comment: You should call `defer.resolve` (or `reject`) outside the promise's `then` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like in your Fiddle you need to call `$timeout.flush()` so the promise resolves...

```
scope.useService();
timeout.flush();  // get timeout from the injector in beforeEach()
rootScope.$digest();
```

You can also simplify the code a lot by chaining and reusing the existing promises. For example, the example above can become...

```
console.log("begin at " + new Date().getTime());
var realPromise = fn.apply(this, arguments);
realPromise.finally(function(result) {
    console.log("end at " + new Date().getTime());
});
return realPromise;
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5L2pxuf7/)